# python: ошибка с оператором != (is not)

Tags: python, telebot, return, sys

Я пишу код, и с целью интереса проверяю как работает оператор !=, мой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def mess(message):
    if message.text == 'Гонка' or message.text == 'гонка':
        users = random.choice([123, 123, 123, 123]) # изменил айди на числа для конфиденциальности 
        if users == f'{message.chat.id}':
            sys.exit()
        if users is not f'{message.chat.id}':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'continue')
```

Проблема в том, что sys.exit не помогает, я пробовал вместо этого писать return, он также не реагирует на это. И ещё проверил это всё без telebot, в чистом файле:

```
inp = input('q: ')
users = random.choice([1, 2, 3])

if inp == 'q':
    users = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
    if users == 1:
        sys.exit()
    elif users != 1:
        print('Продолжаем!')
```

Всё работает, но мне нужно не в чистом файле, а с telebot

Comment: модули sys я импортировал

Comment: Отпечатайте что приходит в строку f'{message.chat.id}', может поэтому на ветку не попадает. message.text можно message.text.lower() .

Comment: В чем, собственно, вопрос?
Что эта программа должна делать, но не делает?

Comment: is not это совсем не !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это выбор одного из целых чисел:

```
users = random.choice([123, 123, 123, 123]) # изменил айди на числа для конфиденциальности
```

А тут выбранное **число** сравнивается со **строкой** (f-строкой):

```
if users == f'{message.chat.id}':
```

Такое условие никогда не сработает. Числа нужно сравнивать с числами, строки со строками. Например, так:

```
if f'{users}' == f'{message.chat.id}':
```

А такая ваша проверка наоборот будет срабатывать всегда:

```
if users is not f'{message.chat.id}':
```

Потому что оператор `is` проверяет, что слева и справа стоит **один и тот же объект**. А два экземпляра **одинаковой** строки - это **разные** объекты:

```
print('123' == f'{123}')
print('123' is not f'{123}')
# True
# True
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!! Теперь команда не работает, но всё же спасибо вам за старания